# pthreads in C: How can I stop the threads from interfering with each other?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads, mutex

I'm new to using pthreads. I want to create a program where six different threads will each output a different number. The threads can run in any order, however, each thread should run only once.

So, a possible output would be:

```
Thread: 5
Thread: 2
Thread: 3
Thread: 6
Thread: 1
Thread: 4
```

Or it could be in any other order.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
    
void *apples(void *void_apple_num){
      int *thread_num = (int *) void_apple_num;
      printf("Thread: %d\n", *thread_num);
      return NULL;
}



int main(){
  pthread_t threads[6];
  int apple_num;
  

  for(apple_num=0; apple_num<6; apple_num++){
       pthread_create(&threads[apple_num], NULL, apples, &apple_num);
  }

  for(apple_num=0; apple_num<6; apple_num++){
       pthread_join(threads[apple_num], NULL);
  }    

  return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, I have this problem of the threads interfering with each other. I am not sure if some of the threads are running twice? However, I think the problem is some of the threads are using the `apple_num` pointer from a different thread.

Here are two sample outputs I got:

Output 1:

```
Thread: 5
Thread: 0
Thread: 1
Thread: 1
Thread: 2
Thread: 2
```

Output 2:

```
Thread: 1
Thread: 4
Thread: 4
Thread: 5
Thread: 1
Thread: 1
```

I don't fully understand what is causing the problem. I've heard that threads can sometimes share variables? I don't know if I should use a mutex lock to somehow get the threads to run one-at-a-time.

How can I edit my code to solve this?

If somebody else has asked a similar question, please direct me to their question. I couldn't find anything when I researching.

Comment: All threads get the address to the same variable from `main` and `main` changes it. You can create an array of numbers and pass the address of one element to each thread.

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to use different processes? `fork()` would behave like you expect.

Comment: Re, "How can I...solve this?" What is "this?" Do you merely want each thread to print a different number? or are you trying to demonstrate how threads can safely share the same variable?

Comment: I want each thread to print a different number

Comment: Read [this pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each of your threads gets a pointer to the very same local variable `apple_num` which is being changed in the loop by the main thread. Since threads start asynchronously, the value of local variable `apple_num` in the main thread is indeterminate from the perspective of any other thread.

You need to pass a *copy* of that variable to each thread.

One fix is to cast `int` to `void*` and back:

```
void *apples(void* apple_num){
    int thread_num = (int)void_apple_num;
...
    pthread_create(&threads[apple_num], NULL, apples, (void*)apple_num);
```

As they mention in the comments, `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` (from `<stdint.h>`) may be more appropriate for round-trip without loss, e.g. `uintptr_t` -> `void*` -> `uintptr_t`. But C standard doesn't require any integers to round-trip to `void*` and back, it only requires `void*` -> `intptr_t` and back.

In a more realistic scenario, you may like to pass more than just one integer to a thread, namely, a `struct`. And that's the rationale for the thread start function to receive a single `void*` argument - it can point to an object of any data type (POSIX requires `void*` to also be able to store function pointers).

An example of passing a structure to a thread (without relying on implementation-defined conversion of integers to `void*` and back):

```
struct ThreadArgs {
    int thread_num;
    // More data members, as needed.
};

void* apples(void* arg){
    struct ThreadArgs* a = arg;
    printf("Thread: %d\n", a->thread_num);
    free(arg);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[6];
    struct ThreadArgs* a;
    int apple_num;

    for(apple_num=0; apple_num<6; apple_num++){
        a = malloc(sizeof *a);
        a->thread_num = apple_num;
        pthread_create(&threads[apple_num], NULL, apples, a);
    }
    
    for(apple_num=0; apple_num<6; apple_num++)
        pthread_join(threads[apple_num], NULL);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Note, that you don't have to allocate the thread arguments structure on the heap (`malloc`). If you pass an automatic variable (on the stack) to a thread, you must make sure that the variable is unchanged and still exists when the thread accesses it. Allocating the thread arguments structure from the heap is the safest and solves this problem at the expense of `malloc`/`free` calls.

Comment: If you store an integer as a pointer, us `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`.

Comment: It depends on what your compilation options are and your tolerance for compiler warnings.  For my purposes, I have zero tolerance for compiler warnings, and converting an `int` to pointer generates a warning/error "cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]" — so I would use `uintptr_t` as suggested.

Comment: It would be better if your answer showed the preferred types.

Comment: You have the round-tripping guarantee backwards.  The standard guarantees that you can round-trip `void *` -> `uintptr_t` -> `void *`, but it is silent about `uintptr_t` -> `void *` -> `uintptr_t`.  One of these does not imply the other in the general case, though in practice you can rely on both in most implementations.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are also quite right, updated.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Would you like to elaborate on your advice?